# Conflicting trait implementation

Tags: rust, traits

I am learning rust and have a hard time to change my c++ architecture mindset into the rust architecture world. Currently I struggle defining common functionality for traits to avoid code duplication.

**Problem**

```rust
trait CommonFunctionality {
    fn common_method(&self) -> i32;
}


trait SpecialFunctionality1 : CommonFunctionality {
    fn special_foo(&self) -> i32;  // defined in actual implementations
}
impl<T: SpecialFunctionality1> CommonFunctionality for T {
    fn common_method(&self) -> i32 {self.special_foo()}
}


trait SpecialFunctionality2 : CommonFunctionality {
    fn special_bar(&self) -> i32;  // defined in actual implementations
}
impl<T: SpecialFunctionality2> CommonFunctionality for T {
    fn common_method(&self) -> i32 {self.special_bar()}
}
```

I don't want to implement the `CommonFunctionality` for every actual struct that I write. So I had the idea using a super-trait in a library. Every actual struct implementation that implements `SpecialFunctionality1` or `SpecialFunctionality2` could get the `CommonFunctionality` without any additional code. Unfortunately this does not compile.

The compiler throws: `error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait 'CommonFunctionality'`

I found similar problem descriptions, but their root cause was that the types where not distinguishable and here `impl<T: SpecialFunctionality1>` and `impl<T: SpecialFunctionality2>` are clearly different types (to my understanding).
When commenting out the last three lines everything compiles.

So, can anyone explain why this is not compile-able?
Or, has someone an advice for coding a better pattern?

**Inefficient Workaround**

What does work is, when I implement the `CommonFunctionality` only for one of the specialized traits.

The traits in my library could look then like this:

```rust
trait CommonFunctionality {
    fn common_method(&self) -> i32;
}

trait SpecialFunctionality1 : CommonFunctionality {
    fn special_foo(&self) -> i32;
}
impl<T: SpecialFunctionality1> CommonFunctionality for T {
    fn common_method(&self) -> i32 {self.special_foo()}
}

trait SpecialFunctionality2 : CommonFunctionality {
    fn special_bar(&self) -> i32;
}
```

While an actual struct implementation of `SpecialFunctionality1` is completely decoupled of the `CommonFunctionality` (while still providing it):

```rust
struct MyStruct1 {
}

impl SpecialFunctionality1 for MyStruct1 {
    fn special_foo(&self) -> i32 {46}
}
```

The actual struct implementation of `SpecialFunctionality2` is completely coupled to the `CommonFunctionality`:

```rust
struct MyStruct2 {
}

impl SpecialFunctionality2 for MyStruct1 {
    fn special_bar(&self) -> i32 {36}
}

impl CommonFunctionality for MyStruct2 {
    fn common_method(&self) -> i32 {self.special_bar()}
}
```

Now the last three lines of code need to be implemented in every actual struct that derives functionality from `SpecialFunctionality2`. This is inefficient implementation effort. And worse: whenever `CommonFunctionality` changes, I have to rework all structs.

Comment: Can you make your examples more concrete? Often times in Rust thinking too abstractly can backfire by leading to too general an architecture. To handle common functionality I will reach for plain helper methods first, then enums. Most of the time enums work out better than traits because you usually know exactly how many variants you're going to have. The flexibility of traits can be a hindrance.

Comment: Sometimes you can inverse your thinking: instead of automatically implementing `CommonFunctionality`, require it as a supertrait and _use_ its implementation in the (possibly default) implementation of `SpecialFunctionality`.

Comment: I thought about bringing the concrete example, but it either messes this thread up with a lot of code or I reduce it and then it is another general example.

@Chayim Friedman: What do you mean with require a supertrait and 'use' its implementation? Do you mean Copy&Paste, or is there a better way?

Comment: You can call any method from supertrait in a trait.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing prevents a new trait or concrete type `FooBar` from implementing both traits `SpecialFunctionality1` and `SpecialFunctionality2`.

In that situation, which specialization should the compiler pick? The one that occurs because `FooBar` implements `...1` or the one that occurs because `FooBar` implements `...2`?

That's where the error comes from.

@john-kugelman already gave some ideas: Helper methods and enums.

There's often a design decision you can make between enums and traits that depend on whether your types are more likely to be exhaustive and controlled by you, as the library's author, or by a user.

If the situation I mentioned above, that a struct implements both of those special functionality traits, should never actually occur, an enum sounds just about right.

In other situations, the way to get code reuse is via the `#[derive]` macro, but I don't have any experience implementing that, and according to @Silvio Mayolo it's tricky and messy.

Comment: Overall good advice, but I probably wouldn't steer a new Rustacean toward `#[derive]`. It's a handy tool, but writing custom derive macros is complicated and tends to get messy, so I tend to prefer it as a last resort.

Comment: Fair point; hence my saying that I have no experience with that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. So 'multi-inheritance' seems not a good idea in rust.

Comment: Actually I was trying to implement a Enum packing method in the 'CommonImplementaion', to be able to handle the Specialized structs objects similar to super-class objects in c++. I guess I'll have to do it with Arc and boxes.

When I started with rust, I read that most people fight with the borrow checker. I think this is not true, the borrow checker and a lot of other features are a blessing. But what I really fight with is learning new software architecture patterns.